# Formally define the ordering of elements in a set

Tags: combinatorics, notation

I would like your help to use a more formal notation for the following assumption that I impose in my problem.

Consider two sets of 4 real numbers  each: $S_1\equiv \{r_1,r_2, r_3, r_4 \}$ and $S_2\equiv \{b_1,b_2, b_3, b_4 \}$.

**My Assumption:** Assume that there exists only one way of ordering the elements of $S_1$ and  only one   way of ordering the elements of  $S_2$ such that
$$
r^o_1+b^o_1<r^o_2+b^o_2<r^o_3+b^o_3<r^o_4+b^o_4
$$
where $r^o_j$ denotes the $j$-th elements in the ordering of $S_1$ and $b^o_j$ denotes the $j$-th elements in the ordering of $S_2$.

What I don't like  in the above is the "o" superscript. I would like to introduce the ordering as a proper function. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can write $r_{f(j)}$, respectively $b_{g(j)}$, where $f$ and $g$ are the permutations of $\lbrace 1,..., 4 \rbrace$ that correspond to your reorderings.